# fluentd k8s how to override tag with rewrite_tag_filter multiple times

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

I am trying to capture both namespace name and the container name while trying to add them to the tag, using the `rewrite_tag_filter`

My goal: The tag should be: <container_name>.<namespace_name>.etc

I was trying to add to my fluentd configuration this block:

```
<match kubernetes.**>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key $.kubernetes.namespace_name
    pattern ^(.+)$
    tag $1.${tag}
  </rule>
</match>
```

This did the trick of adding the namespace_name, but I also want to concatenate to it the container_name

I tried:

```
<match kubernetes.**>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key $.kubernetes.namespace_name
    pattern ^(.+)$
    tag $1.${tag}
  </rule>
</match>
<match kubernetes.**>
 @type rewrite_tag_filter
 <rule>
   key $.kubernetes.container_name
   pattern ^(.+)$
   tag $1.${tag}
 </rule>
</match>
```

I also tried to directly pass the container_name while capturing the namespace name as the key, still no luck:

```
<match kubernetes.**>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key $.kubernetes.namespace_name
    pattern ^(.+)$
    tag $1.${$.kubernetes.container_name}.${tag}
  </rule>
</match>
```

Still did not work